# Regex to check if string contains anything other than allowed words

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to check if a string contains any word other than some predefined ones. The predefined words are `What is,plus,minus,multiplied by,divided by`, single whitespace included in some of the phrases. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31254518/839733) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/839733), both using negative lookaheads, but couldn't come up with a pattern that worked.

For example, input text "What is plus abc divided by" should come back as "abc" not recognized.

What would be a correct regex for this?

**Edit:**

Note that I don't care about *what* the invalid token is, just that it exists. It can be anything, a word or a number. The question can also be thought as "check if the input contains only allowed words".

Comment: May the input contain other "non word" characters, eg may the input be `"What is 5 plus 3"`?

Comment: @Bohemian, yes. I've edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Some edge cases to think about: `undivided by`, `What issue`, `plusses`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join them up in a group:

```
(?:What is|plus|minus|multiplied by|divided by)
```

Note that if you have, for example, `multiply` and `multiply by` (i.e. one token that starts with another), `multiply by` *must* comes first:

```
(?:What is|plus|minus|multiply by|multiply)
```

To check if the string only contains valid tokens, use:

```
^                  # Match at the start of string
\g<token>          # a pre-defined token
(?:\s+\g<token>)*  # followed by 0 or more tokens
$                  # right before the end of string.
```

...where `\g<token>` denotes the expression above.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QQeVJk/2).

## Original answer

Since we also need to find the (first) invalid token, you need to match every non-whitespace streaks and store those which are not matched by the expression above in a group:

```
(?:What is|plus|minus|multiplied by|divided by)|(\S+)
```

If the match contains group 1, that means it is a non-recognized token. Output an error accordingly.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QQeVJk/1).

Comment: I don't need to capture the invalid token, just need to know if it exists. I've edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because it matches almost anything.

Comment: @Bohemian How does it match "almost anything", given that valid tokens are pre-defined?

Comment: What *doesn't* it match is the question. See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/p5k3WZPS2A9Xpc) and add some more examples yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: @Bohemian That regex is in the original answer which I have noted as such (at first, I thought OP needs a nice error message rather than just a boolean). Have you tried the new one then?

Comment: `^(?:\g<token>\s*)+$` seems to be simpler and does the job using your examples. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar If you want `What isplus` to match, then yes. You can shorten the regex to [`^(?:\g<token>(?:\s+|$))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/QQeVJk/4), but I think that wouldn't be as readable.

Comment: @InSync "What isplus" isn't valid. So, sounds like, I got my solution. On hindsight, it's really simple, not sure why I was confused with lookaheads. I'm keeping your answer as accepted as I got my idea from it.

Comment: I know that isn't valid, I'm presenting it as a counter-example since `^(?:\g<token>\s*)+$` matches it.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... check if the input contains only allowed words".*

You would have to then check the result to see if the non-specified value is allowed.

```
What is +(.+?) +(?:plus|minus) +(.+?) +(?:(?:multiplied|divided) by) +(.+)
```

Alternately, specify the values.  In this case it's most likely numbers only.

```
What is +(\d+) +(?:plus|minus) +(\d+) +(?:(?:multiplied|divided) by) +(\d+)
```

Example

```
What is 1 plus 2 divided by 3
```

The output would be 1, 2, and 3.

And, ultimately allow for fractional values.

```
What is +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) +(?:plus|minus) +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) +(?:(?:multiplied|divided) by) +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

```
What is 1.23 plus 2.3 divided by 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a negative look ahead to try to match the whole input being *not* being made of just the allowed phrases:

```
^(?!((^| )(What is|plus|minus|multiplied by|divided by)( |$))+$).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/LSOzfHF2GoP0qK).

Comment: Fails for "What is plus divided by abc". I found something that passes my tests, mentioned in my comment to @InSync's answer. `^(?:\g<token>\s*)+$`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar oops - left out the `$` at the end of the look ahead. Regex and demo link updated.